# How does a value from a previous level in recursion go back up?

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

I'm trying to make a recursive function to get minimum number of coins for change, but I think my understanding of what each layer's return value in the stack is wrong. What I want is for the coin amount to be passed back up when the recursion reaches it's base case, but looking at the debugger, the coin case decreases on the way back up.

I've already tried to look at solutions for this problem, but they all seem to use dynamic programming, and I know that it's more efficient in terms of complexity, but I want to figure out how to do the recursion before adding the dynamic programming portion

```
def min_coin(coin_list, value, counter = 0):
    if value == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        for coin in coin_list:
            if coin <= value:
                sub_result = value - coin

                min_coin(coin_list, sub_result, counter)
                counter +=1
                return counter


                #counter += 1 #should add returning out from,
    #return counter

coin_list = [5, 2, 1]
value = 8

print(min_coin(coin_list,value))
```

I want an output of 3, but the actual output is 1 no matter the value

Answer (score 0):

You need to increment the counter before calling `min_coin()`.

```
def min_coin(coin_list, value, counter = 0):
    if value == 0:
        return counter
    else:
        for coin in coin_list:
            if coin <= value:
                sub_result = value - coin
                return min_coin(coin_list, sub_result, counter+1)
```

Comment: If I’m understanding this correctly, the base case is returning the counter at the end, so every call is returning the end counter? Isn’t the base case suppose to return the simplest case where recursion isn’t needed e.g if no coins given then return 0.

Comment: @hopelessly_lost_at_coding The base case is when value is 0, and you return the counter. If value is 0 at the first call to the function, the counter is 0 (since it is the first call), so returning the counter works. When value is not 0, you subtract the coin from value, increment the counter, and call the function again with the updated value and counter. At this point you check if the updated value is 0. If it is, you return the counter, (which is now 1). If not, you repeat this process until value is 0, and the function return the counter.

Answer (score -1):

You can solve your task without recursion, answer from [geekforcoders](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/greedy-algorithm-to-find-minimum-number-of-coins)

```
# Python 3 program to find minimum  
# number of denominations 

def findMin(V): 

    # All denominations of Indian Currency 
    deno = [1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50,  
            100, 500, 1000] 
    n = len(deno) 

    # Initialize Result 
    ans = [] 

    # Traverse through all denomination 
    i = n - 1
    while(i >= 0): 

        # Find denominations 
        while (V >= deno[i]): 
            V -= deno[i] 
            ans.append(deno[i]) 

        i -= 1

    # Print result 
    for i in range(len(ans)): 
        print(ans[i], end = " ") 

# Driver Code 
if __name__ == '__main__': 
    n = 93
    print("Following is minimal number", 
          "of change for", n, ": ", end = "") 
    findMin(n)
```